# from anshu.myapp.views import TaskViewSet ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anshu.myapp'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using rest framework with Django. My working directory and project is shown below.

When I run the server I get the error is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anshu.myapp'
```

Please help me.

```
anshu
    anshu
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    myapp
        migrations
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        Serializers.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    manage.py
```

This is my settings file.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'rest_framework',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import TaskViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'task',TaskViewSet)

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^',include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

views.py

```
from .models import Task
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .Serializers import TaskSerializer


class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    task_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    task_desc=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

In urls file from "anshu.myapp.views import TaskViewSet" is the problem to not run the server

I am using:-

```
python = 3
django = 2.0.3
rest_framework = 3.8.2
```

Traceback

```
(py1) C:\Users\NIKITA GULHANE\nehal\anshu>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. 
<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000019A3FBB8B70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in 
inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", 
line 397, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", 
line 536, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", 
line 529, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\NIKITA GULHANE\nehal\anshu\anshu\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
from .views import TaskViewSet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anshu.views'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your outer `anshu` directory is on the Python path, so you should not include the `anshu` prefix when importing `myapp`. Change it to:

```
from myapp.views import TaskViewSet
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.viewsets' has no attribute 'Model'

Comment: The traceback shows that you haven't fixed `from anshu.myapp.views` yet.

Comment: from myapp.views  is not available in django packeges

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Copying parts of the error message isn't enough. You need to show the code that causes the error and the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change it to the following code as As Answered by @Alasdair

```
from myapp.views import TaskViewSet
```

or

```
from .views import TaskViewSet
```

Another issue is with views.py

it is `viewsets.ModelViewSet`, not `viewsets.Model.ViewSet`.

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
```

Comment: thanks for code correction but after code modification same error is occur

Comment: .view is not avalable in packages of django

Comment: @nehalgulhane it is `.views` not `.view`

Comment: sorry, but ".views" is not available in packages